# Multiple Keybinding to a single command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, key-bindings

My window has just a listview. This facilitates the users to incremental search the db. Since the design does not have a textbox, i've to globally handle the keys. I think it could be achieved by keybinding. But how can i handle all the keys and associate it to a single command.

Also suggest me other methods if any.

P.S.: I want this in xaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an EventToCommand binding the KeyDown event to a command on the ViewModel. You can set PassEventArgsToCommand to true, and use a RelayCommand to find out what key as pressed.

All these objects are available in the MVVM Light Toolkit

http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Can you also provide some samples/Demo-Videos on how to use the Messenger class in MVVM Light? Your demo on MVVM Light in SilverlightTV does not cover Messenger Class. Thanks.

Comment: For the Messenger, see my MIX10 video where I show an introduction to this class:
http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX14

Also, check a much more meaty sample here:
http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/10/18/clean-shutdown-in-silverlight-and-wpf-applications.aspx